# block read of instance variable when trying to set it

Tags: python, thread-safety

````
Class A(object):
  def __init__(self, cookie):
    self.__cookie = cookie

  def refresh_cookie():
    ```This method refresh the cookie after every 10 min```
    self.__cookie = <newcookie>

  @property
  def cookie(self):
    return self.__cookie
````

Problem is cookie value gets changed after every 10 min. However if some method already had the older cookie then request fails. This happen when multiple threads using the same A object.
I am looking for some solution where whenever we tries to refresh i.e. modify cookie value no one should be able to read the cookie value rather there should be a lock at cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a condition variable.

````
from threading import Lock, Condition

class A(object):
  def __init__(self, cookie):
    self.__cookie = cookie
    self.refreshing = Condition()

  def refresh_cookie():
    ```This method refresh the cookie after every 10 min```
    with self.refreshing:
        self.__cookie = <newcookie>
        self.refreshing.notifyAll()

  @property
  def cookie(self):
    with self.refreshing:
        return self.__cookie
````

Only one thread can enter a `with` block governed by `self.refreshing` at a time. The first thread to try will succeed; the others will block until the first leaves its `with` block.